# How to create bean edit model for Map in Tapestry?

Tags: java, properties, dictionary, edit, tapestry

I'm having a `Map<String, Boolean>` which I'd like to edit values from via BeanEditor.

I've been poking around and figured I need to create my own property conduit for it:

```
public class MapPropertyConduit implements PropertyConduit {

    private Object key;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Class dataType;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public MapPropertyConduit(Object key, Class dataType) {
        this.key = key;
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Object get(Object instance) {
        return ((Map) instance).get(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void set(Object instance, Object value) {
        ((Map) instance).put(key, value);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class getPropertyType() {
        return dataType;
    }

}
```

I initialized it like this:

```
this.reportingModel = beanModelSource.createEditModel(Map.class, messages);

MViewTransactionDisplayModel selectedModel = getMViewTransactionReportModel();
Map<String, Boolean> displayFields = selectedModel.getDisplayModel();

for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry : displayFields.entrySet()) {
    this.reportingModel.add(entry.getKey(), new MapPropertyConduit(entry.getKey(), Boolean.class)).dataType(Boolean.class.getName());
}
```

In my `tml` I did this:

```
<t:beaneditor t:id="mapEditorId" t:object="myMap" t:model="reportingModel"/>
```

And the exception I get is:

```
Render queue error in BeginRender[MyPage:mapeditorid.propertyeditor]: Unable to locate a block to edit property 'property1' (with data type 'java.lang.Boolean') of object {property1=true, property2=true, property3=true, property4=true, property5=true, property6=true, property7=true, property8=true, property9=true, property10=true, property11=true, property12=true, property13=true}: There is no defined way to edit data of type 'java.lang.Boolean'. Make a contribution to the BeanBlockSource service for this type.
```

I am kind of puzzled since I was under the impression that I can edit `Boolean`s with a simple checkbox.

It's either that, or I failed on providing/calling custom property conduit?

Is there a way to fix this so I can freely edit the values in a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example of using a `MapPropertyConduit` [here](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/mapgriddemo)

You might also be interested in the `map:` binding prefix [here](http://tapestry-stitch.uklance.cloudbees.net/mapbindingdemo)

Comment: Both links seam no longer to work. I think that is why references to external sources are discouraged for questions and answers.

Comment: The code can be found on his github though for the interested: https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-stitch

Answer (score 1):

When I changed

```
this.reportingModel.add(entry.getKey(), new MapPropertyConduit(entry.getKey(), Boolean.class)).dataType(Boolean.class.getName());
```

to

```
this.reportingModel.add(entry.getKey(), new MapPropertyConduit(entry.getKey(), Boolean.class)).dataType("boolean");
```

it suddenly worked.

Does anyone have a complete list of available data types?

Comment: These are defined in [TapestryModule](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/8b7be0060db3b4995896211eae26242559ece227/tapestry-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tapestry5/modules/TapestryModule.java#L632)